# Simulating connection problems for .NET HttpWebRequest

Tags: .net, testing, httpwebrequest, connection

Are there ways to programmatically simulate connection problems (slow connection, response does not complete, connection gets dropped, etc.) when using the HttpWebRequest class?

Thanks

EDIT: To elaborate more, I need this for debugging but would want to turn it into a test eventually. I'm using the async methods BeginGetRequestStream, EndGetRequestStream, BeginGetResponse and EndGetResponse. I have wrapped them all in proper (I hope) Try Catch blocks which log the exceptions that happen.

I know this works for some cases (e.g. when I pull out the network cable). But on some rare occasions (i.e. only when the website I'm requesting is slow) then my system crashes and I get this in the Event Log

```
Exception: System.Net.WebException

Message: The request was aborted: The connection was closed unexpectedly.

StackTrace:    at System.Net.ConnectStream.BeginRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.ReadCallback(IAsyncResult baseStreamResult)
   at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
   at System.Net.ContextAwareResult.CompleteCallback(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.ContextAwareResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
   at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(Object result, IntPtr userToken)
   at System.Net.Sockets.BaseOverlappedAsyncResult.CompletionPortCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
   at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
```

I am making an assumption it's from HttpWebRequest but then again all my code is wrapped in Try Catch blocks.

Would mocks help in such a case?

Comment: No, mocks will not help in that situation, as you do not know what causes your request to abort. I would guess that there is a proxy between your client app and the server you connect to, which closes the connection. Or the server itself closes it as unused. More information is needed.

Comment: Not much more info I can provide. Funny thing is it only seems to happen when the 3rd party's website is slow. And to top it off, the Event Log message doesn't even have my own code's method in the stack trace. It's been a lot of guess work and cable pulling shenanigans so far =/

Answer (score 3):

@Chris 
Unfortunately, Microsoft neglected to [make many of the BCL objects easily mockable](http://bartling.blogspot.com/2009/01/net-base-class-library-types-not.html), as they tend to use abstract classes, and .NET classes are closed by design (in other words, for a method to be overridden by a subclass, it needs to be explicitly marked as virtual), whereas Java is open by design (that is, a subclass can override any method, unless they are marked as final). Using interfaces or marking the methods as virtual would have saved a lot of headaches in the testing space. Microsoft may have the testability religion now (e.g. ASP.NET MVC), but it's a bit late for the BCL.

Typemock Isolator [may be able to help](http://blog.typemock.com/2008/07/is-visibility-of-tested-methods.html), but I don't believe Moq can, in this case.

Comment: +1 David, the non-extensibility of MS libraries, like WinForms, to quote another example, is absolutely frustrating.

Answer (score 2):

If this is for testing purposes - i.e. to inspect your's code behavior, I would suggest to create a class which inherits from from HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse, and override the methods you are interested in to behave the way you want - i.e. Thread.Sleep for delays, throw an exceptions, etc.

Comment: I was going to suggest doing the same thing.  :-)

Comment: Bad advice. MSDN guides against inheriting from HttpWebRequest http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx (second para under remarks).

Answer (score 0):

If you're in control of the site that's responding to the request, I'd say putting the thread to sleep for a while would simulate a slow response.  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(number of milliseconds)

As for a dropped connection, I can't think of anything programmatic, but I've literally pulled out my network cable to simulate that condition.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are writing unit tests to cover the code, you could use a mocking framework (I personally prefer [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/)) to mock out the implementation of the HttpWebRequest for any  virtual methods on the class.  In your mock, you can do your own implementation of how you want the test case to behave.